# Is there a neural network or feature available which can synthesize speech from a voice?

Tags: sound

Consider the following [VoCo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Voco) project from [Adobe](https://research.adobe.com/project/voco-text-based-insertion-and-replacement-in-audio-narration/).

In it they show how they are able to take 20 mins of speech and create additional narration in the same voice very accurately.

- [Video1 (Nov-2016)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3l4XLZ59iw)
- [Video2 (May-2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB7upq8nzIU)

Is there a neural net or something that is available in the language that can produce similar results.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no network likes this exists in the language or the neural network repository at present, but that's not to say it's impossible to build!